# Does MongoDB have a Ruby Shell or Python Shell in addition to the Javascript shell?

Tags: python, ruby, mongodb, nosql

Or, does using Ruby's irb and then `require 'mongo'` and adding some Connect
statement essentially act like a Ruby shell...  it would be great if a
Ruby shell can be possible which as convenient as the Javascript
Shell.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is fundamentally correct. I mean, as long as the language can handle command-line interpretation *and* support a MongoDB driver, then you could theoretically build a new MongoDB shell.

However, I regularly read through the MongoDB mailing lists and I think that you're kind of on your own for this idea right now. Hey, writing a Ruby shell for Mongo would be an awesome way to learn a lot about Mongo. However, the current Mongo community is still relatively small and no one is really complaining too much about the javascript shell.

Answer (score 0):

You may find [hirb](http://github.com/cldwalker/hirb) handy for [creating ascii tables from mongodb objects](http://tagaholic.me/2010/03/11/hirb-and-tables-for-all.html#mongo_mapper).